# Is there a way in GTM to create a variable tracking the product category of a checkout conversion without duplicate categories?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I currently have a custom variable that pulls ecommerce information out of the data layer and returns with the product categories for that purchase. I did this through two custom variables - the first being "PurchaseProducts", which has the data layer variable of "ecommerce.purchase.products", and then making a second Custom JavaScript variable with the code

```
function () { return {{PurchaseProducts}}.map(function(a) {return a.category;}); }
```

This does work on returning the categories for that purchase, however it seems to be returning the category of each item. (For example, "Produce, Produce, Pantry, Health and Beauty, Specialty Cheese, Pantry")

Is there a way to adjust the code to have the different categories be pulled but not have the duplicates? Or should I look into having separate variables for each of the categories?

Answer (score 0):

You just need something like remove duplicate in JavaScript array.

Here is a way:

```
var arr = ["apple", "mango", "apple", "orange", "mango", "mango"];
var unique = arr.reduce(function (acc, curr) {
    if (!acc.includes(curr))
        acc.push(curr);
    return acc;
}, []);
console.log(unique);
```

---

If you search about it. Make sure you are not using JS ES6 since Google Tag Manager not support it. If you are not familiar, when you see `const`, `let`, `=>` in the code. It is ES6 and paste it in GTM will show error when previewing.